# Broadleaf Commerce Database Alias missing

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have been able to run broadleaf demo site from eclipse luna but when I run tomcat task of the admin sub-module I am getting the following stack trace .
Sorry for the long stack trace but I thought the full context will be more helpful then a curtailed version .

```
[artifact:mvn] Aug 24, 2015 3:49:06 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext      lookup
[artifact:mvn] WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
[artifact:mvn] java.sql.SQLException: General error: database alias does not exist
[artifact:mvn]  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
```

I have made no alterations to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the embedded HSQL instance (looks like you are) you need to start up the `site` project first. The `site` project depends on an ant `start-db` task that ensures that the HSQL database is started up.

Also, the `site` task will also auto-import some SQL with an example catalog representative of the heat clinic sample data.

Comment: I did run the ant task named "Tomcat" of the site sub-project before I ran the tomcat task of the admin sub-module . The site module is running fine but the admin module is posing problems .

Comment: I did run the ant task named "Tomcat" of the site sub-project before I ran the tomcat task of the admin sub-module . The site module is running fine but the admin module is posing problems . I read the getting started guide throughly before running the ant tasks but still ran into this problem . I think the getting started guide does not cover all the situations that a developer may face . Please provide some solutions to this .

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem . Went through a lot of trouble before finding out that the problem gets solved when I do a clean install with maven before running the tomcat task of the admin module . Try it I hope you get the same results .